# Cleaning text throughout a dataframe column with python

Tags: python, nlp

I am messing around with the genius lyrics API in an attempt to analyze the lyrics of certain artists. I am currently stuck trying to get rid of all the unwanted characters from the data. My dataframe looks like [this]

[image: 1].

I want to get rid of '/n' and all instances of the song structure notation contained within square brackets([verse1],[verse2],[intro]...). I have tried different regex approaches but none seem to work.

Comment: Please share the attempt you were most surprised about not working and people will be able to improve on it. Also, please provide a sample of the relevant data in your question as text, not just an image.

Comment: When adding information to a question, you should edit the question instead of putting information in the comments - the comments are hard to read and editing the question avoids the next person having to dig through all the comments.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *regex* for your approach.

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'song_title' : ['Easy Easy', 'Baby Blue'],
                   'lyrics' : ['[verse1]\nwell same old', '[verse2]\nmy same old']
                   })
```

**Code**

```
pattern = r'(\[[^]]*\])(\n)'
df['lyrics'].map(lambda x:re.sub(pattern,'',x))
```

Comment: Please don't post the same verbose, hard to read comment twice in to the same question - this is not even really a response to this author's answer.